# YAML Configuration replace one property value for the value of another

Tags: yaml

I would like to know if it is possible to replace the value of one value for the value of another one, like e.g. :

```
booking:    
    services:
      dans:
        PRIVATE_KEY: MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAr8nAQCQZ8hL0up8LzItKrBwIWhvbFgTtVEHjQIJ0Yw/F3u82         
      mode:
         PRIVATE_KEY: {booking.services.dans.PRIVATE_KEY}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use anchors and aliases:

```yaml
booking:    
    services:
      dans:
        PRIVATE_KEY: &a
          MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAr8nAQCQZ8hL0up8LzItKrBwIWhvbFgTtVEHjQIJ0Yw/F3u82         
      mode:
         PRIVATE_KEY: *a
```

This is not a replacement, but a reference; both `PRIVATE_KEY` keys will link to the same value.

YAML does not provide a way to refer to other values via some kind of path. Mind that `{}` in YAML do have a special meaning; they create flow mappings. What you wrote is equivalent to this:

```yaml
booking:    
    services:
      dans:
        PRIVATE_KEY: MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAr8nAQCQZ8hL0up8LzItKrBwIWhvbFgTtVEHjQIJ0Yw/F3u82         
      mode:
         PRIVATE_KEY:
             booking.services.dans.PRIVATE_KEY:
```